# Sorting by Date instead of day

Tags: java, sorting, date

How to sort the event by date, when I try it, it is sorting by daywise however it is not sorting by date.

For example, if we have three events on 01/02/2018, 23/04/2018, 01/06/2018, the current result sort like the below, [01/02/2018,01/06/2018,23/04/2018]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you write your code on stackoverflow (in a code block) instead of just taking a screenshot?

Comment: I see no attempt at any kind of sorting, and why is all the code inside an XML comment (`<!--`)?

Comment: This is unclear in more than one way, sorry. Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and specify precise input with examples, precise expected output and how observed output differs, please?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`, `TimeZone`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those class are all long outdated and poorly designed. Instead use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is much nicer to work with.

Comment: Is `order by eventFrom` part of an SQL query or other query? What is the datatype of `eventFrom` in the database? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Andreas, let me guess, this is part of a JSP page and commented out because it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because your `eventFrom` column in your database has a character type (like `varchar(10)`, for example). When you do `order by eventFrom`, the database is sorting the strings, not the dates that you and I see in the strings. This gives ordering first by day of month since this comes first in your string, then if the day of month is the same, by month, and finally by year. So `01/02/2018` comes before `01/06/2018` because they have the same day of month and `02` comes before `06`.

The two obvious fixes are

- Best use datatype `date` for your database column. Then sorting will be chronological like you expected.
- If your database doesn’t offer a `date` datatype (which by all likelihood it does), store your dates in a string format with year first, then month and day of month last. I recommend you use ISO 8601 format since this is a widely used standard and not likely to get you into any trouble. Then your dates will look like `2018-02-01`, `2018-04-23` and `2018-06-01`, and sorting will be as expected.

I mentioned in a comment that you are using outdated date and time classes. The class from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, that you need is `LocalDate`. “Local” means without time zone, and “date” means a date without time of day, so this fits more nicely than the old-fashioned `Date` and `Calendar`. Another very nice thing is that `LocalDate.toString()` produces exactly the ISO 8601 format I mentioned. If you cannot avoid the string format, this will be handy: you won’t need any explicit formatter for producing the format used in your database. Also `LocalDate.parse()` parses the same format back into a `LocalDate` object without a formatter.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)